# No me cargan los estilos Bootstrap

Tags: java, html, bootstrap, netbeans, google-app-engine

buenos dias,

Tengo una plantilla HTML que usa bootstrap, pero no me cargan los estilos estoy usando NetBeans 8 y el servidor App Engine. asi estoy creando las referencias:

```
<link href="../src/java/font-awesome/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../src/java/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../src/java/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../src/java/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Los archivos se encuentran en esas rutas.

Este el el error que obtengo:

```
 [java] dic 19, 2017 10:57:32 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
 [java] ADVERTENCIA: No file found for: /src/java/font-awesome/font-awesome.css
 [java] dic 19, 2017 10:57:32 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
 [java] ADVERTENCIA: No file found for: /src/java/css/bootstrap.min.css
 [java] dic 19, 2017 10:57:32 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
 [java] ADVERTENCIA: No file found for: /src/java/css/style.css
 [java] dic 19, 2017 10:57:32 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
 [java] ADVERTENCIA: No file found for: /src/java/css/animate.css
```

Alguien sabe que pueda estar pasando, problema con el servidor App Engine.

Comment: Podrías publicar algo mas de información sobre tu proyecto por ejemplo si te marca alguna error el log de tu explorador. en que parte estas declarando estas rutas. entre otra información

Comment: Prueba primero a cargarlo de manera online, por ejemplo `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`, para descartar que sea cualquier otro fallo que no sea del `CSS`

Comment: ya agregue mas detalle @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia gracias

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura no me lo carga tampoco, me genera el error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Comment: por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Intenta quitar el ../,recuerda que ../ regresara un directorio atrás de donde se este ejecutando tu archivo (php o html) o habré el código fuente dentro del navegador y examina la ruta que esta generando.

Answer (score 2):

Asumo que estás haciendo una aplicación y usas Maven (o quizá Gradle) para hacer el build:

La carpeta /src/java es donde debe estar el código fuente de Java, sólo archivos .java. Maven compilará esos archivos y volcará los resultantes (con extensión .class) a WEB-INF/classes, con lo que no serán accesibles desde fuera del servidor

La carpeta /src/resources es donde deben estar los recursos "estáticos" de la aplicación, pero que son privados. Estos se copian también a WEB-INF/classes y suelen ser archivos .properties o spring-context.xml, por ejemplo.

La carpeta /src/webapp es donde debes poner tus archivos CSS, HTML, JSP o Javascript. La ruta será la raíz de tu aplicación. Por tanto, si pones algo en /src/webapp/css, el navegador podrá acceder con la URL tipo /css

Puedes ver los detalles [aquí](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Al trabajar en un proyecto App Engine los recursos web deberían ubicarse dentro de la carpeta webapp. La carpeta src/java esta dedicada para el código fuente Java.